# Python Pandas advanced filter on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with integer column and 20M rows. I would like to filter the dataframe such that each value in the column will repeat at most 1000 times.

Right now I can only do the iteration over randomly ordered dataframe rows. Any idea to use pandas magic to inline the query into dataframe filter?

```
class_2_counts = defaultdict(int)
random_subset = []
random_order = np.random.permutation(dataframe.index)
        
for row_idx in random_order:
    class_idx = dataframe["column_name"][row_idx]
    if class_2_counts[class_idx] >= 1000:
        continue
    # we are adding this row to dataset
    class_2_counts[class_idx] += 1
    random_subset.append(row_idx)
        
random_subset = sorted(random_subset)
ret_val = dataframe.iloc[random_subset]
```

UPDATE:
I ended up with this solution:

```
def filter_rows(group, max_repeat_count):
    return group.sample(frac=1).head(max_repeat_count)
new_idcs = dataframe.groupby(classifier, group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(filter_rows, 1000).index
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC the following will be the idiomatic way to do this with Pandas:

First, I'm randomly shuffling the rows (not sure if you require this step), then using a `groupby` to get a `cumcount`. You can then use that cumcount column to filter the dataset for your required threshold.

```
# init with a smaller random dataset
n = 1000
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':rng.integers(0,10, size=(n))})
threshold =10 # define threshold here

df2 = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=rng) # random shuffle all rows 
df2['col_count'] = df2.groupby('col').cumcount()
df2 = df[df['col_count']  < threshold].drop(columns=['col_count'])
```

Comparing this solution vs your original solution 1000 times, and timing it shows that this solution ~2x faster as well.

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('f()', globals=globals(),number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit('g()', globals=globals(),number=1000))
```

prints:

```
6.23
3.13
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, what you want is

```
threshold = 1
df.sample(frac=1)[lambda df_: df_.groupby('A').cumcount().lt(threshold)].sort_index()
```

- `.sample(frac=1)` is to shuffle the dataframe like you loop over `np.random.permutation(dataframe.index)`
- `.groupby('A').cumcount()` is to count the occurrence of repeated value like you do `class_2_counts[class_idx] += 1`
- `df[...].sort_index()` is to select the satisfied rows like you do `dataframe.iloc[random_subset]`

Given a following dataframe

```
    A
0  10
1  20
2  30
3  40
4  50
5  60
6  70
7  10
8  20
9  80
```

If you do

```
a = df.sample(frac=1)
a['count'] = a.groupby('A').cumcount()
a['mask']  = a['count'] < threshold
```

Current `a` might be

```
print(a)

    A  count   mask
4  50      0   True
2  30      0   True
6  70      0   True
3  40      0   True
7  10      0   True
1  20      0   True
0  10      1  False
9  80      0   True
5  60      0   True
8  20      1  False

print(a[a['mask']])
    A  count  mask
4  50      0  True
2  30      0  True
6  70      0  True
3  40      0  True
7  10      0  True
1  20      0  True
9  80      0  True
5  60      0  True
```

From the `mask` column, we see that index `0` and `8` will be dropped. That can be done with `a[a['mask']]`.